# Why is the pCode type const uint32_t*? (pCode in VkShaderModuleCreateInfo )?

Tags: vulkan

I just read the [Shader Modules](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules) Vulkan tutorial, and I didn't understand something.

Why is `createInfo.pCode` a `uint32_t` rather than `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`? Is it faster? (because moving pointer is now 4 bytes)?

```
VkShaderModule createShaderModule(const std::vector<char>& code) {
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.codeSize = code.size();
    createInfo.pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(code.data());
    VkShaderModule shaderModule;
    if (vkCreateShaderModule(device, &createInfo, nullptr, &shaderModule) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create shader module!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you propose otherwise and why?

Comment: Probably because SPIR-V is a stream of 32-bit instructions. Having the pointer match that ensures correct alignment.

Comment: Asking for the rationale behind an API decision is not "opinion based". I disagree with the close vote.

Comment: @Frank it kinda is, because only the autors can know the official rationale. Everyone else can only have opinions. It is relatively clear in this case though...

Comment: @krOoze If only the authors know the rationale, then they can answer the question accurately. There are plenty of questions out there that only a very small subset of programmers are equipped to answer confidently, and that does not make them opinion-based.

Comment: @Frank Think whatever you want. There's a diff between information being public but only smart and specialized people knowing it, and there is information being private or internal. Everyone that was not listening on Khronos meetings can have an **opinion** what the rationale was, but only the person rationalizing can **know** the rationale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SPIR-V module is defined a stream of 32-bit words. Passing in data using a `uint32_t` pointer tells the driver that the data is 32-bit aligned and allows the shader compiler in the driver to directly access the data using aligned 32-bit loads.

This is usually faster (in most CPU designs) than random unaligned access, in particular for cases that cross cache lines.

This is also more portable C/C++.  Using direct unaligned memory access instructions is possible in most CPU architectures, but not standard in the language. The portable alternative using a byte stream requires assembling 4 byte loads and merging them, which is less efficient than just making a direct aligned word load.

Note using `reinterpret_cast` here assumes the data is aligned correctly. For the base address of `std::vector` it will work (data allocated via `new` must be aligned enough for the largest supported primitive type), but it's one to watch out for if you change where the code comes from in future.

Comment: SPIR-V does not have 32-bit instructions. It has 32-bit words. Instructions can be, and often are longer, being made of one or more words.

Answer (score 1):

According to [VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-parameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-parameter), the specification requires that:

> pCode must be a valid pointer to an array of  `4/codeSize` `uint32_t` values

`pCode` being a `uint32_t*` allows this requirement to be partially validated by the compiler, making it one less thing to worry about for users of the API.

Comment: It validates nothing if you reinterpret_cast stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Because SPIR-V word is 32 bits.

It should not matter for performance. It is just a type.